# Bypass capacitor calculation for power support

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, resistors, bypass-capacitor

[image: circuit]

"A bypass capacitor is a capacitor that bypasses, or shunts, unwanted AC signals on a DC line. This allows the DC signal to be more purely DC and less noisy."

[image: pic]

[image: voltage charge]

https://www.redcrab-software.com/en/Calculator/Electrics/C-Charge-State

The reactance of 68pF is about 117 ohm at a frequency of 20 MHz.
The current of yellow arrowed input and the current of the DC voltage source(+5V) in the circuit above, have a summed current at the base of bc547 transistor.
Say, the voltage charge calculator has calculated correctly, so the current of the collector for this transistor should be about 42mA to support the 20Mhz oscillation and the necessary power with a 68pF capacitor.

Can you tell me, if I am on a right way? I tested this circuit, because I soldered the components together and tried it, so I know it is working. All I need is more knowledge about this concept.
By the way, I am software designer and I am just upgrading and looking for a chance in electronics.

Comment: ok, give me some time. I will provide details.

Comment: I tried to provide some information. The circuit at the beginning, I have seen on Internet made me think about this bypass - capacitor calculation.

Comment: Can you give me any hint, why this circuit at the beginning of this post can work?

Comment: The 47k resistor has nothing to do with the crystal, it is for biasing the base. If the circuit was drawn the way they are supposed to be with ground at the bottom and power at the top, input on the left and output on the right, it would be more clear.

Comment: I don't understand the roundabout presentation: we can tell what a bypass cap is, you don't need to introduce it to us. If you just want an explanation of how the circuit operates, please just say so; include background information so we can know what level to write to (introductory fundamentals, amplifiers, control systems, RF circuitry, etc.). I'm guessing you aren't a native English speaker; the language barrier may simply be too steep, I am afraid. Have you had any luck finding local resources?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I want to know how to the 68pF capacitor in the introduced circuit, had been calculated. Because it is working. Earlier, I tried a 4.7pF and it did not work. Then I tried a 22pF it was working slightly, but not efficient enough. So why?